# How to contain a Sqlalchemy query into a Python variable?

Tags: python, loops, variables, sqlalchemy

I have 12 if/else statements in my codes, each one will query with Sqlalchemy differently like below:

```
if condition1:
  query1 = s.query(Invoice).filter(Invoice.trading_partner_name==trading_partner_name).all()

elif condition2:
  query2 = s.query(Invoice).filter(...).all()

elif condition3:
  query3 = s.query(Invoice).filter(...).all()

elif condition 4... and so on
```

and then I want to display each of the query above with the code (or similar code to this one) below:

```
             for data in query1:
                [a few other very long codes]
```

I can put the codes above after each query results in each if/else statement, but that would make my codes very long and redundant. I tried to create a variable that I hoped to hold the value of each query:

```
query_variable = 0
```

then I tried to set this variable to each query variable in each if/else statement like below:

```
if condition1:
  query1 = s.query(Invoice).filter(Invoice.trading_partner_name==trading_partner_name).all()
  query_variable = query1

elif condition2:
  query2 = s.query(Invoice).filter(...).all()
  query_variable = query2

elif condition3:
  query3 = s.query(Invoice).filter(...).all()
  query_variable = query3

elif condition 4... and so on
```

and then I tried substitute the query_all variable above into the loop of the long codes like below:

```
            for data in query_variable:
                [a few other very long codes]
```

However, it didn't work. When I run to code to query data from query_variable, I got the error below:

```
 TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

I tried to find answers on StackOverflow, but I couldn't...
If you knows how to fix this problem/ or the answer to "how to contain a Sqlalchemy query into a Python variable?", pls help me!

I would greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: can you `print(query_variable)` before the for loop? The best option is to write a function and pass it `trading_partner_name` depending on the condition, then the function will do the query and processing.

Comment: it says 0....@Epsi95

Comment: That means none of your conditions were satisfied and your initial assignment `query_variable = 0` stayed. Check your conditions and ass else at the end to handle what you want to do if no conditions are met.

Comment: ok, thank you very much. I will check why this happens:)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, thanks a lot to @Epsi95, my problem was because I was testing some of my conditions is not met. To hold a sqlalchemy query, you can do the same as I did, and it works:)